# Alternative for concurrency:: data structures in macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, c++11, cocoa, data-structures

For my macOS application, I'd like to use concurrent map and queue data structure to be shared between multithread process and support parallel operations.

After some research I've found what what I need, but unfortunately those are only implemented in windows.

`concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<key,value>` `concurrency::concurrent_queue<key>`

Perhaps there are synonyms internal implementations in macOS in CoreFoundation or other framework that comes with Xcode SDK (disregarding the language implementation) ?

thanks,

Comment: Did you take a look of [Intel TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perhaps there are synonyms internal implementations in macOS in CoreFoundation or other framework that comes with Xcode SDK (disregarding the language implementation) ?

Nope. You must roll-your-own or source elsewhere.

The Apple provided collections are not thread safe, however the common recommendation is to combine them with [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch?language=objc) (GCD) to provide lightweight thread-safe wrappers, and this is quite easy to do.

Here is an outline of one way to do it for [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary?language=objc), which you would use for your concurrent map:

1. Write a subclass, say `ThreadSafeDictionary`, of `NSMutabableDictionary`. This will allow your thread safe version to be passed anywhere an `NSMutableDictionary` is accepted.
2. The subclass should have a private instance of a standard `NSMutableDictionary`, say `actualDictionary`
3. To subclass `NSMutableDicitonary` you just need to override 2 methods from `NSMutableDictionary` and 4 methods from [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc). Each of these methods should invoke the same method on `actualDictionary` after meeting any concurrency requirements.
4. To handle concurrency requirements the subclass should first create a private concurrent dispatch queue using [`dispatch_queue_create()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create) and save this in an instance variable, say `operationQueue`.
5. For operations which *read* from the dictionary the override method uses a [`dispatch_sync()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452870-dispatch_sync?language=objc) to schedule the read on `actualDicitonary` and return the value. As `operationQueue` is concurrent this allows multiple concurrent readers.
6. For operations which *write* to the dictionary the override method uses a [`dispatch_async_barrier()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452797-dispatch_barrier_async) to schedule the write on `actualDicitonary`. The async means the writer is allowed to continue without waiting for any other writers, and the barrier ensures there are no other concurrent operations mutating the dictionary.

You repeat the above outline to implement the concurrent queue based on one of the other collection types.

If after studying the documentation you get stuck on the design or implementation ask a new question, show what you have, describe the issue, include a link back to this question so people can follow the thread, and someone will undoubtedly help you take the next step.

HTH